# How to Convert OData to LINQ supporting GraphDB

Tags: linq, asp.net-core-mvc, odata, sparql, graphdb

The below code is transforming OData filter to LINQ, but it is SQL dependent. I want to connect it with GraphDB, i.e., it should extract entities from graph, but I'm unable to understand how to proceed.

```
public IQueryable<AssetGroup> Get (ODataQueryOptions<AssetGroup> query)
{
    var items = query.ApplyTo(from i in _db.Assets select i);
    return (IQueryable < AssetGroup >) items;
}
```

Comment: unable to do what? query GraphDB triple store? either use plain HTTP via your DotNet app or use a lib like [`dotNetRDF`](https://www.dotnetrdf.org/) which does most things for you

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Do you want to *replace* OData endpoints by a GraphQL endpoint? Or is the main issue how to get rid of SQL dependency? Your question needs more background.

Comment: I want to get rid of SQL dependency and make it model independent(here Assets is model) . Such that it should fetch data dynamically from server of graph database.